# Carousel indicatorView doesn't automatically update on Windows while scrolling

Tags: .net, xaml, carousel, maui-windows

In my MAUI test app to figure out by practice how work a carousel view, I noticed that my `IndicatorView` element doesn't update on Windows Machine while scrolling threw my carousel's items.

On Android it work when sliding from one to the next though.

Here is my XAML code :

```
<ScrollView>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="LightCoral">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>                
            <RowDefinition Height="410"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>          
        <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding CarouselGrids}" IndicatorView="indic"
                      HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="400"
                      Loop="False" BackgroundColor="PaleGoldenrod">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- Not relevant here-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>            
        <IndicatorView Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" IndicatorSize="22" IndicatorsShape="Circle"
                       IndicatorColor="Gainsboro" SelectedIndicatorColor="#006EFF"
                       x:Name="indic" />            
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

Note that when directly clicking work on indicators, the carousel still navigate to the correct item.

Here is a gif of this issue
[image]

Comment: Do you mean it worked correctly on the android? In addition, did you try the sample in the official document?

Comment: Yes on android emulated device, the indicator view work. Didn't try the sample (I guess you are referring to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples) ?)

Comment: No, this is [the sample](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/6.0/UserInterface/Views/CarouselViewDemos) and you can try to test it.

Comment: Tested it, and same issue as I'm experiencing.
The Indicator doesn't update on Windows Machine scrolling through Carousel's Items !

Comment: Which version of visual studio you used? In addition, you can report it on the github.

Comment: VS 2022 17.4 preview 5. I opened an issue on Maui Example GitHub (that also pointing back here) : https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/issues/260

Comment: But it seems the newest version is 2022 17.4 preview 1.

Comment: Yes, sorry I made a mistake to calling that from memory. Actually checking in About section, it is "Version 17.4.0 Preview 1.0".